# UIWebView scrollsToTop and ignores UIEdgeInsets in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I basically have a Title bar with a UIWebView behind it. I have set the UIEdgeInsets of the UIWebView.scrollView to be such that the top of the Web page is at the bottom of the Title bar. Everything works as I expect except when the web page loads it moves the top of the UIWebView and ignores the UIEdgeInsets.

The behavior is particularly strange because while a web page is loading, parts of the web page are shown and are in the correct position (with the top of the web page just below the Title bar as it should be because of the UIEdgeInsets). However, once the web page completes loading it suddenly jumps up to the top of the UIWebView and ignores the UIEdgeInsets.

The workaround I am currently using is to set the contentOffset to the correct position immediately after the page loads, but this is not ideal because you can see it jumping to the top of the UIWebView then jumping back down to the bottom of the Title bar.

Does anyone know if there is something I can do to stop it jumping to the top of the UIWebView, either by forcing it to ignore the message to scroll to CGPointZero, or by setting the 'Start Position' to be the at the bottom of the title bar (please note, I have tried setting the origin to this point and it did not resolve the issue)?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks